# Postgres Count with different condition on the same query

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, inner-join

I'm working on a report which has this following schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fd104/2

The current query is working fine which looks like this:

[image]

Basically it is a 3 table inner join. I did not make this query but the developer who left it and I want to modify the query. As you can see, `TotalApplication` just counts the total application based on the `a.agent_id`. And you can see the `totalapplication` column in the result. What I want is to remove that and change the `totalapplication` to a new two column. I want to add a `completedsurvey` and `partitalsurvey` column. So basically this part will become

```
SELECT a.agent_id as agent_id, COUNT(a.id) as CompletedSurvey
FROM forms a WHERE  a.created_at >= '2015-08-01' AND 
a.created_at <= '2015-08-31' AND disposition = 'Completed Survey'
GROUP BY a.agent_id
```

I just added `AND disposition = 'Completed Survey'` But I need another column for `partialsurvey` which has the same query with `completedsurvey` being the only difference is

```
AND disposition = 'Partial Survey'
```

and

```
COUNT(a.id) as PartialSurvey
```

But I dunno where to put that query or how will be the query look like.So the final output has these columns

```
agent_id, name, completedsurvey, partialsurvey, loginhours, applicationperhour, rph
```

Once it is ok then applicationperhour and rph I can fix it myself

Comment: Cross post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112796/postgres-count-with-different-condition-on-the-same-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a filtered (conditional) aggregate:

```
SELECT a.agent_id as agent_id, 
       COUNT(a.id) filter (where disposition = 'Completed Survey') as CompletedSurvey, 
       count(a.id) filter (where disposition = 'Partial Survey') as partial_survey
FROM forms a 
WHERE a.created_at >= '2015-08-01' 
  AND a.created_at <= '2015-08-31' 
GROUP BY a.agent_id;
```

The above assumes the current version of Postgres (which is 9.4 at the time of writing). For older versions (< 9.4) you need to use a `case` statement as the `filter` condition is not supported there:

```
SELECT a.agent_id as agent_id, 
       COUNT(case when disposition = 'Completed Survey' then a.id end) as CompletedSurvey, 
       COUNT(case when disposition = 'Partial Survey' then a.id end) as partial_survey
FROM forms a 
WHERE a.created_at >= '2015-08-01' 
  AND a.created_at <= '2015-08-31' 
GROUP BY a.agent_id;
```